# Highstock MACD Study is using sma instead of ema

Tags: highcharts

I am using the macd chart study and it is using a sma by default. The macd should be calculated using the difference between the 12 and 26 day ema. What parameter(s) do I need to set to use ema instead of sma? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunatelly, I cannot agree with your statement. Of course, `macd` indicator inherits some prototype functions and default parameters from `sma`, but the `getValues` function (which is responsible for calculating the values) is overridden by new one, where the values are calculated in the way that you described above. Here is the most important part of that functions code:

```
               getValues: function (series, params) {
                    var j = 0,
                        MACD = [],
                        xMACD = [],
                        yMACD = [],
                        signalLine = [],
                        shortEMA,
                        longEMA,
                        i;

                    if (series.xData.length < params.longPeriod) {
                        return false;
                    }

                    // Calculating the short and long EMA used when calculating the MACD
                    shortEMA = EMA.prototype.getValues(series,
                        {
                            period: params.shortPeriod
                        }
                    );

                    longEMA = EMA.prototype.getValues(series,
                        {
                            period: params.longPeriod
                        }
                    );

                    shortEMA = shortEMA.values;
                    longEMA = longEMA.values;


                    // Subtract each Y value from the EMA's and create the new dataset
                    // (MACD)
                    for (i = 1; i <= shortEMA.length; i++) {
                        if (
                            defined(longEMA[i - 1]) &&
                            defined(longEMA[i - 1][1]) &&
                            defined(shortEMA[i + params.shortPeriod + 1]) &&
                            defined(shortEMA[i + params.shortPeriod + 1][0])
                            ) {
                            MACD.push([
                                shortEMA[i + params.shortPeriod + 1][0],
                                0,
                                null,
                                shortEMA[i + params.shortPeriod + 1][1] -
                                    longEMA[i - 1][1]
                            ]);
                        }
                    }

                    // Set the Y and X data of the MACD. This is used in calculating the
                    // signal line.
                    for (i = 0; i < MACD.length; i++) {
                        xMACD.push(MACD[i][0]);
                        yMACD.push([0, null, MACD[i][3]]);
                    }

                    // Setting the signalline (Signal Line: X-day EMA of MACD line).
                    signalLine = EMA.prototype.getValues(
                        {
                            xData: xMACD,
                            yData: yMACD
                        },
                        {
                            period: params.signalPeriod,
                            index: 2
                        }
                    );

                    signalLine = signalLine.values;

                    // Setting the MACD Histogram. In comparison to the loop with pure
                    // MACD this loop uses MACD x value not xData.
                    for (i = 0; i < MACD.length; i++) {
                        if (MACD[i][0] >= signalLine[0][0]) { // detect the first point

                            MACD[i][2] = signalLine[j][1];
                            yMACD[i] = [0, signalLine[j][1], MACD[i][3]];

                            if (MACD[i][3] === null) {
                                MACD[i][1] = 0;
                                yMACD[i][0] = 0;
                            } else {
                                MACD[i][1] = (MACD[i][3] - signalLine[j][1]);
                                yMACD[i][0] = (MACD[i][3] - signalLine[j][1]);
                            }

                            j++;
                        }
                    }

                    return {
                        values: MACD,
                        xData: xMACD,
                        yData: yMACD
                    };
                }
```

Here is the link, where you can see whole code of `macd.src.js` indicator:
https://code.highcharts.com/stock/indicators/macd.src.js

Kind regards!

**[EDIT]**

After conversation in comments, we noticed that the EMA is currently calculated basing on `open` values from OHLC dataset, instead of `close` values, and definitely is a bug. I reported the new issue on our GitHub repo here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/8951 so you can watch the progress of fixing it, but it should be fixed with new upcoming Highstock version (v7).

To workaround it, you can simply overrride the `seriesTypes.macd.prototype.getValues` function, so that it will pass the `index: 3` in params, when calculating short and long `EMA`'s.
Here is the code to apply before initializing any charts:

```
(function(H) {
  var EMA = H.seriesTypes.ema,
    defined = H.defined;

  H.seriesTypes.macd.prototype.getValues = function(series, params) {
    var j = 0,
      MACD = [],
      xMACD = [],
      yMACD = [],
      signalLine = [],
      shortEMA,
      longEMA,
      i;

    if (series.xData.length < params.longPeriod) {
      return false;
    }

    // Calculating the short and long EMA used when calculating the MACD
    shortEMA = EMA.prototype.getValues(series, {
      period: params.shortPeriod,
      index: 3
    });

    longEMA = EMA.prototype.getValues(series, {
      period: params.longPeriod,
      index: 3
    });

    shortEMA = shortEMA.values;
    longEMA = longEMA.values;


    // Subtract each Y value from the EMA's and create the new dataset
    // (MACD)
    for (i = 1; i <= shortEMA.length; i++) {
      if (
        defined(longEMA[i - 1]) &&
        defined(longEMA[i - 1][1]) &&
        defined(shortEMA[i + params.shortPeriod + 1]) &&
        defined(shortEMA[i + params.shortPeriod + 1][0])
      ) {
        MACD.push([
          shortEMA[i + params.shortPeriod + 1][0],
          0,
          null,
          shortEMA[i + params.shortPeriod + 1][1] -
          longEMA[i - 1][1]
        ]);
      }
    }

    // Set the Y and X data of the MACD. This is used in calculating the
    // signal line.
    for (i = 0; i < MACD.length; i++) {
      xMACD.push(MACD[i][0]);
      yMACD.push([0, null, MACD[i][3]]);
    }

    // Setting the signalline (Signal Line: X-day EMA of MACD line).
    signalLine = EMA.prototype.getValues({
      xData: xMACD,
      yData: yMACD
    }, {
      period: params.signalPeriod,
      index: 2
    });

    signalLine = signalLine.values;

    // Setting the MACD Histogram. In comparison to the loop with pure
    // MACD this loop uses MACD x value not xData.
    for (i = 0; i < MACD.length; i++) {
      if (MACD[i][0] >= signalLine[0][0]) { // detect the first point

        MACD[i][2] = signalLine[j][1];
        yMACD[i] = [0, signalLine[j][1], MACD[i][3]];

        if (MACD[i][3] === null) {
          MACD[i][1] = 0;
          yMACD[i][0] = 0;
        } else {
          MACD[i][1] = (MACD[i][3] - signalLine[j][1]);
          yMACD[i][0] = (MACD[i][3] - signalLine[j][1]);
        }

        j++;
      }
    }

    return {
      values: MACD,
      xData: xMACD,
      yData: yMACD
    };
  }
})(Highcharts)
```

**Live example:** http://jsfiddle.net/aL1bqn2f/

Comment: Hello, Daniel. You are correct. However, when I add a 12 and 26 day ema to my chart and subtract the 26 from the 12, I get the correct value of the macd. But, it is not the same value shown in the legend. The legend shows a macd value of 6.03 today for aapl. However, the correct value of macd today is 5.48. I am using a candlestick chart and this is the code for the macd. Thank you.

Comment: I created the example where added the EMA (12), and EMA (26) manually, and you can see that the values are calculated properly: http://jsfiddle.net/0psjaLqh/

Comment: Your script in the fiddle is not using the closing price for the EMA. The EMA used to calculate the MACD is based on closing prices. The EMA (12) and EMA (26) were not correct. I added "index: 3" to the EMA params to specifically use the closing price from the ohlc series. Now, if you subtract the EMA (26) (216.4980) from the EMA (12) (221.3780) you will see that the MACD is not correct. MACD should be (4.88). I updated the fiddle. [link] (http://jsfiddle.net/0psjaLqh/5/). How do I get the MACD to use closing prices? That looks like the problem. Is that what you think is happening? Thank you.

Comment: You're definitely right. Thank you for this report. I've updated the answer above, so please refer to it.

Comment: Thank you, Daniel. You have a great product. Have a good weekend.

Comment: Is this fixed? I'm using highcharts 8.1.0 (the latest as of 5/17/2020) and still see this problem. There are several issues as I observed: SMA and MACD use open price, while WMA and EMA use close price. I also think EMA calculation is not quite right for the first "period" point because it uses SMA - shouldn't it use the EMA based on the available points?

Comment: @BobbyWWilson This bug has been fixed, and EMA calculations are based on the third index on the data array by default, what you can read in the documentation (https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.ema.params.index). Until closing price is put on the last position in the data array, then EMA will be calculated from it.

Regarding SMA and MACD, yes they are using open prices, but you can simply change that behaviour by setting params.index value to 3 (https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.sma.params.index) and the problem disappears.

Comment: @BobbyWWilson Answering to your question about EMA and it starting point, a given day's EMA calculation depends on the EMA calculations for all the days prior to that day, and because EMA has to start somewhere, a simple moving average have to be used as the previous period's EMA in the first calculation.